# Databinding in windows forms on an object graph with possible null properties?

Tags: winforms, data-binding

If I have an object graph like this:

```
class Company {
  public Address MainAddress {...}
}

class Address {
  public string City { ... }
}

Company c = new Company();
c.MainAddress = new Address();
c.MainAddress.City = "Stockholm";
```

and databind to a control using:

```
textBox1.DataBinding.Add( "Text", c, "MainAddress.City" );
```

Everything is fine, but If I bind to:

```
Company c2 = new Company();
```

`c2` using the same syntax it crashes since the `MainAddress` property is null. I wonder if there is a custom Binding class that can set up listeners for all the possible paths here and bind to the actual object dynamically when/if I sometime later in the application set the `MainAddress` property.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the getter of the property MainAddress to do this null check, and return an "empty MainAddress"

Comment: Is this still recommended approach? I've been trying to figure out how to best solve this problem for ages.